# Allow Users to Leave (Exit) a Direct Message conversation

Tags: customer-community, direct-messaging

Is there any way to allow a customer community user to leave (exit) a Direct Message conversation (one-on-one or group Direct Message chat?)

Nothing I have found in Salesforce [help regarding Salesforce Communities](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_overview.htm&type=5) even mentions this feature, much less state if it is or is not possible. In fact, there is a surprising lack of documentation around direct messaging in general.; there isn't even a "Direct Messaging" tag in this Salesforce StackExchange.

Comment: At your link, in the left sidebar, expand Setting Up a Community > Enable Other Salesforce Features in Communities > Enable Direct Messages in Your Community. Or here's a [direct link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_enable_direct_messages.htm&type=5).

Comment: @ThomasTaylor your explanation is for how to enable direct messages. My question is how to allow users to leave a direct message conversation.

Comment: Ah - you mean remove themselves from a Direct Message thread once it's been started? Sorry - I didn't understand from your question. "Leave a message" is often used to mean "send a message".

Comment: @ThomasTaylor makes sense. I've updated the post to hopefully clarify this